# Restarting ESP8266 NodeMCU in DeepSleep with a signal from HM10 BLE

Tags: low-power, esp8266, bluetooth-low-energy, reset, power-consumption

I'm building a simple project in which I put the ESP8266 NodeMCU board in DeepSleep mode, so I can save some battery since it's powered with 4 AA batteries.

What's the problem?
I don't want my ESP to wakeup in every x seconds, I want it to only wake up when the HM10 receives a signal.

I had a HC-05 bluetooth module before, in which I connected the TX to the RST pin of the ESP8266 to force it to restart and that was working fine, but once again due to power saving I decided to switch from de HC-05 to the HM10.

So the wires between the HM10/HC-05 and the ESP8266 NodeMCU are the following:

**HM10/HC-05 - ESP8266 NodeMCU**

- VCC - 3.3V
- GND - GND
- TX - RST/EN

I did some tests and I got the following results **when the ESP8266 is in DeepSleep**:

1. **HC-05 TX connected to RST pin:** OK (esp8266 restarted)
2. **HC-05 TX connected to EN pin:** Nothing happens
3. **HM10 TX connected to RST pin:** Nothing happens
4. **HM10 TX connected to EN pin:** Nothing happens

And when the **ESP8266 is just running without DeepSleep**:

1. **HC-05 TX connected to RST pin:** OK (esp8266 restarted)
2. **HC-05 TX connected to EN pin:** OK (esp8266 restarted)
3. **HM10 TX connected to RST pin:** Nothing happens
4. **HM10 TX connected to EN pin:** OK (esp8266 restarted)

So I find this behavior a little bit weird. Is there any simple explanation for this?

**Conclusion: I just need my HM10 BLE to be able to restart the ESP8266 when it is in DeepSleep mode.**

My HM10 BLE is this one: https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B07NJ1881X/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: To get this to work you're going to need to document the idle and active state of the serial line that you are trying to re-purpose as a wakeup trigger, or even find a way to customize software to drive something else.  Really though this project sounds like a kludge; consider using a single chip if possible, or at least gain full control of the BLE device firmware so that you can handle the ESP8266 with comprehensive care.

Comment: @ChrisStratton but do you have any explanation for the case in which the bluetooth module HC-05 can reset the ESP board when in DeepSleep mode through the RST pin, and the HM10 can't? 

Or why the HC-05 can't restart from the EN pin when the ESP is in DeepSleep but it works when the ESP is not in DeepSleep?

Comment: As asked, that's an off topic "usage" question.  To be on topic, you're going to have to detemine and compare the specific behavior of the devices - how does their output signal differ?.  My gut feeling is that you will end up having to run your own custom firmware on the BLE MCU to get this to work, ie, insteading of calling it an HM10 you will start thinking of it as a CC2540 + your firmware; or replace it (and maybe the ESP as well) with something like an nRF52 series part.